# How do I fix this strange screen that shows when I turn my Debian computer on?

Tags: debian, startup

[image]

This shows up when I startup Debian. Is this a problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you notice the error message with a URL to visit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel is letting you know that your system needs [additional firmware](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) to enable all its features.

To install this firmware, you first need to enable the “non-free” repositories; as root, run

```
sed -i.bak 's/stretch[^ ]* main$/& contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then

```
apt update
```

This will allow you to install the missing firmware:

```
apt install firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-iwlwifi
```

Then you need to update your initramfs:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot.

Comment: I did as you said, the installation was correct but the screen keeps apearing

Comment: With exactly the same messages?